# Name of datastructure that implements a dictionary of indexed queue or linked list?

Tags: data-structures

A lookup table with a finite number of keys, pointing to specific indexes in a changing linked list(or a form of indexed linked list anyway) or queue or a dropoutstack (this is what i m using atm).

Comment: what exactly are you asking?

Comment: I think, I just didn't figure this out when I was asking this...I wanted a fast lookup for the first 100elements of a structure. in the end I just  created a wrapper class around the data structure and I have a 100 element dictionary which is accessed via [indexer++%maxsize]

Comment: So is there anything you want?

Comment: What I m working on is a fast lookup of the last 100packets received in a tcp connection, so I m using the silly approach above to ask if a packet has been assembled for that referenced state, if you have any advice on how to approach that, it would be grateful.

Comment: Typically that's called an LRU cache.